# Fourier series fit doesn't consider different local maxima of the data

Tags: plotting, fitting, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to appropriately fit a fourier model to experimental data. But the problem is that the resulting fit doesn't consider the varying local maxima of the data.

Here's the data:

```
data={{0., 1.62103}, {1.59924, 1.67994}, {3.19848, 1.76026}, {4.79772, 
  1.80673}, {6.39696, 1.8598}, {7.9962, 1.86282}, {9.59544, 
  1.87166}, {11.2114, 1.87156}, {12.7939, 1.87728}, {14.4099, 
  1.82449}, {15.9925, 1.80886}, {17.5918, 1.79485}, {19.191, 
  1.75784}, {20.807, 1.73654}, {22.4062, 1.70686}, {24.0054, 
  1.66943}, {25.6047, 1.63784}, {27.2039, 1.64295}, {28.8032, 
  1.59652}, {31.3354, 1.58473}, {32.9346, 1.56336}, {34.5339, 
  1.53878}, {36.1331, 1.51662}, {37.749, 1.52651}, {39.3483, 
  1.48455}, {40.931, 1.47545}, {42.5468, 1.47792}, {44.1461, 
  1.46984}, {45.7454, 1.45691}, {47.3612, 1.44064}, {48.9606, 
  1.42462}, {50.5598, 1.41207}, {52.159, 1.39475}, {53.7583, 
  1.38704}, {55.3575, 1.39879}, {56.9568, 1.38317}, {58.556, 
  1.39112}, {60.1552, 1.38762}, {62.7207, 1.38232}, {64.3201, 
  1.38509}, {65.9026, 1.39164}, {67.5019, 1.38518}, {69.1011, 
  1.39424}, {70.6838, 1.41042}, {72.283, 1.40475}, {73.8823, 
  1.4228}, {75.4815, 1.43597}, {77.0808, 1.43705}, {78.6967, 
  1.47911}, {80.2792, 1.5015}, {81.8952, 1.52173}, {83.4944, 
  1.54084}, {85.1103, 1.56518}, {86.7096, 1.60301}, {88.3255, 
  1.64637}, {89.9248, 1.69936}, {91.5073, 1.73079}, {94.0729, 
  1.76966}, {95.6722, 1.79222}, {97.2714, 1.78713}, {98.8706, 
  1.79135}, {100.47, 1.75675}, {102.069, 1.74179}, {103.668, 
  1.73523}, {105.268, 1.71698}, {106.867, 1.69583}, {108.466, 
  1.68806}, {110.049, 1.67025}, {111.648, 1.63703}, {113.247, 
  1.626}, {114.846, 1.59278}, {116.446, 1.56201}, {118.045, 
  1.58105}, {119.644, 1.55918}, {121.244, 1.53408}, {122.843, 
  1.53606}, {125.392, 1.51481}, {126.991, 1.5071}, {128.607, 
  1.50275}, {130.189, 1.48783}, {131.789, 1.46677}, {133.388, 
  1.46361}, {134.987, 1.47924}, {136.586, 1.45564}, {138.169, 
  1.45476}, {139.768, 1.43951}, {141.367, 1.44018}, {142.983, 
  1.42988}, {144.599, 1.42606}, {146.199, 1.41682}, {147.781, 
  1.41454}, {149.38, 1.42971}, {150.963, 1.42491}, {152.562, 
  1.42664}, {154.162, 1.42002}, {156.71, 1.43735}, {158.31, 
  1.43401}, {159.909, 1.4527}, {161.508, 1.43911}, {163.107, 
  1.4441}, {164.723, 1.45954}, {166.323, 1.4343}, {167.922, 
  1.46126}, {169.504, 1.48359}, {171.104, 1.48829}, {172.703, 
  1.49519}, {174.302, 1.50245}, {175.901, 1.53872}, {177.517, 
  1.55181}, {179.117, 1.58608}, {180.716, 1.59239}, {182.315, 
  1.633}, {183.914, 1.63106}, {185.514, 1.64767}, {188.062, 
  1.67233}, {189.662, 1.67241}, {191.244, 1.66006}, {192.844, 
  1.68123}, {194.443, 1.67911}, {196.042, 1.6684}, {197.658, 
  1.66663}, {199.257, 1.65853}, {200.857, 1.64544}, {202.472, 
  1.63608}, {204.072, 1.61669}, {205.654, 1.61556}, {207.254, 
  1.59515}, {208.853, 1.58351}, {210.452, 1.56633}, {212.051, 
  1.55562}, {213.651, 1.54092}, {215.25, 1.51884}, {216.866, 
  1.52626}, {219.431, 1.51675}, {221.03, 1.50742}, {222.63, 
  1.49369}, {224.212, 1.47495}, {225.812, 1.47253}, {227.411, 
  1.45261}, {229.01, 1.45637}, {230.609, 1.43563}, {232.225, 
  1.42526}, {233.808, 1.41891}, {235.407, 1.42398}, {236.99, 
  1.4137}, {238.606, 1.41656}, {240.205, 1.40668}, {241.804, 
  1.40326}, {243.387, 1.39673}, {244.986, 1.39886}, {246.585, 
  1.38496}, {248.184, 1.39534}, {250.75, 1.40539}, {252.349, 
  1.41112}, {253.948, 1.41193}, {255.548, 1.42339}, {257.147, 
  1.44511}, {258.746, 1.43922}, {260.329, 1.4712}, {261.928, 
  1.48333}, {263.544, 1.50475}, {265.127, 1.55252}, {266.726, 
  1.58253}, {268.325, 1.64951}, {269.924, 1.7048}, {271.524, 
  1.77026}, {273.106, 1.82019}, {274.705, 1.84745}, {276.305, 
  1.8618}, {277.887, 1.86067}, {279.487, 1.85571}, {282.052, 
  1.82686}, {283.651, 1.8172}, {285.251, 1.78734}, {286.85, 
  1.76062}, {288.432, 1.73714}, {290.032, 1.71213}, {291.631, 
  1.68495}, {293.247, 1.65939}, {294.829, 1.64458}, {296.429, 
  1.6325}, {298.045, 1.58712}, {299.627, 1.5676}, {301.243, 
  1.55351}, {302.842, 1.52739}, {304.442, 1.51368}, {306.041, 
  1.52018}, {307.657, 1.50288}, {309.239, 1.48562}, {310.839, 
  1.47884}, {313.404, 1.45589}, {315.003, 1.44615}, {316.603, 
  1.44958}, {318.202, 1.42828}, {319.801, 1.42421}, {321.417, 
  1.40902}, {323., 1.40048}, {324.599, 1.39907}, {326.182, 
  1.39556}, {329.397, 1.37646}, {330.996, 1.38923}, {332.595, 
  1.38914}, {334.178, 1.39418}, {335.777, 1.39506}, {337.393, 
  1.37884}, {338.992, 1.39638}, {340.592, 1.41348}, {342.191, 
  1.41578}, {344.74, 1.46429}, {346.339, 1.47461}, {347.938, 
  1.50045}, {349.521, 1.54545}, {351.137, 1.58719}, {352.736, 
  1.64857}, {354.335, 1.68838}, {355.934, 1.74357}, {357.534, 
  1.80062}, {359.133, 1.8446}, {360.732, 1.86921}, {362.331, 
  1.87709}, {363.914, 1.86407}, {365.53, 1.83981}, {367.129, 
  1.83959}, {368.728, 1.80868}, {370.328, 1.80399}, {371.927, 
  1.77087}, {373.51, 1.75285}, {375.109, 1.71898}, {376.708, 
  1.69569}, {378.307, 1.67887}, {379.907, 1.65734}, {381.522, 
  1.61742}, {383.122, 1.596}, {386.703, 1.56191}, {388.303, 
  1.54718}, {389.902, 1.53308}, {391.501, 1.51604}, {393.084, 
  1.50679}, {394.7, 1.48916}, {396.299, 1.48208}, {397.898, 
  1.46974}, {399.497, 1.4646}, {401.097, 1.45299}, {402.696, 
  1.45232}, {404.279, 1.43553}, {405.878, 1.42497}, {407.477, 
  1.42119}, {409.06, 1.41202}, {410.659, 1.40749}, {412.258, 
  1.40855}, {413.857, 1.41359}, {415.457, 1.41076}, {417.989, 
  1.40651}, {419.588, 1.41757}, {421.187, 1.41581}, {422.787, 
  1.41994}, {424.386, 1.42134}, {425.968, 1.42441}, {427.568, 
  1.43257}, {429.184, 1.44978}, {430.8, 1.45837}, {432.382, 
  1.47002}, {433.981, 1.48139}, {435.581, 1.49949}, {437.18, 
  1.52456}, {438.779, 1.53323}, {440.378, 1.5712}, {441.978, 
  1.59066}, {443.56, 1.61338}, {445.143, 1.6351}, {446.759, 
  1.66504}, {449.324, 1.68336}, {450.924, 1.68639}, {452.523, 
  1.68708}, {454.139, 1.6813}, {455.738, 1.68519}, {457.337, 
  1.67114}, {458.936, 1.65698}, {460.519, 1.65152}, {462.102, 
  1.64747}, {463.701, 1.63251}, {465.3, 1.62152}, {466.899, 
  1.61931}, {468.499, 1.59303}, {470.098, 1.58356}, {471.681, 
  1.58228}, {473.28, 1.57347}, {474.879, 1.56006}, {476.478, 
  1.53452}, {478.061, 1.53139}, {480.643, 1.51941}, {482.226, 
  1.51783}, {483.825, 1.48705}, {485.424, 1.4959}, {487.007, 
  1.49279}, {488.623, 1.48235}, {490.222, 1.47662}, {491.805, 
  1.44583}, {493.404, 1.45701}, {495.02, 1.4549}, {496.619, 
  1.44729}, {498.201, 1.4378}, {499.801, 1.43419}, {501.4, 
  1.42368}, {502.999, 1.41367}, {504.599, 1.41577}, {506.198, 
  1.40778}, {507.78, 1.41046}, {509.38, 1.41262}, {511.945, 
  1.40732}, {513.544, 1.40493}, {515.144, 1.393}, {516.743, 
  1.41062}, {518.342, 1.41157}, {519.941, 1.40709}, {521.524, 
  1.41336}, {523.123, 1.42273}, {524.722, 1.44338}, {526.305, 
  1.45494}, {527.904, 1.47173}, {529.504, 1.49501}, {531.103, 
  1.53354}, {532.685, 1.55843}, {534.285, 1.58945}, {535.884, 
  1.61907}, {537.483, 1.64483}, {539.066, 1.68931}, {540.682, 
  1.71184}, {543.231, 1.75192}, {544.813, 1.76839}, {546.429, 
  1.77242}, {548.028, 1.75339}, {549.611, 1.73661}, {551.21, 
  1.72117}, {552.809, 1.7048}, {554.392, 1.6911}, {555.991, 
  1.67447}, {557.591, 1.65868}, {559.207, 1.64152}, {560.789, 
  1.62177}, {562.372, 1.6041}, {563.988, 1.58738}, {565.587, 
  1.57031}, {567.186, 1.55374}, {568.802, 1.54545}, {570.401, 
  1.50809}, {572.001, 1.51358}}
```

And here's what I've tried so far:

```
k=4
modelK = a0 + 
   Sum[b[i]*Sin[2*Pi*i*t/P] + d[i]*Cos[2*Pi*i*t/P], {i, 1, k}];
paramsK = 
  Join[{a0}, Table[b[i], {i, 1, k}], Table[d[i], {i, 1, k}], {P}];
B[t_] = FindFit[data, {modelK, {85 < P < 90}}, 
  paramsK, t]
fitPlotK = 
  Plot[modelK /. B[t], {t, 0, 575}, PlotStyle -> Black, Frame -> True];
```

The parameter P got specified to as close to the literary value as possible

Plotting the fitted model and the data it looks like this:

[image: Data fitted with the Fourier model]

Now the question is how to modify the model or initial parameters for the fit to better resemble the experimental data.

Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your fit,because of the restriction `85 < P < 90`, only fits the basic vibration of your data. Extend the model with harmonics of the complete period `P0=Max[data[[All,1]]]` and increase `k` to get better fit:

```
k = 2 4
P0 = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
modelK = a0 + 
   Sum[b[i]*Sin[2*Pi*i*t/P] + d[i]*Cos[2*Pi*i*t/P], {i, 1, k}] + 
   Sum[bb[i]*Sin[2*Pi*i*t/P0] + dd[i]*Cos[2*Pi*i*t/P0], {i, 1, k}];
paramsK = 
  Join[{a0}, Table[b[i], {i, 1, k}], Table[d[i], {i, 1, k}], 
   Table[bb[i], {i, 1, k}], Table[dd[i], {i, 1, k}], {P}];
B[t_] = FindFit[data, {modelK , {85 < P < 90}  }, paramsK, t]
fitPlotK = 
 Show[{Plot[modelK /. B[t], {t, 0, 575}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
    Frame -> True] , ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]}, 
  PlotRange -> {1, 2}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot :D

Comment: @xPigeonDestroyer2000 You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you mean by "fit" and what you need to use it for.  (And this is more of an extended comment rather than an answer.)

If you are just wanting to obtain a function that reproduces the data (and only within *Mathematica*), then interpolation might be what you want:

```
f = Interpolation[data];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[f[t], {t, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image: Data and fit by interpolation]

If a function like the insightful answer by @UlrichNeumann is what you want (a smooth curve using 34 parameters to summarize 347 data points), then using `NonlinearModelFit` rather than `FindFit` will give you an assortment of goodness-of-fit statistics including prediction bands:

```
k = 2*4;
P0 = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
modelK = a0 + Sum[b[i]*Sin[2*Pi*i*t/P] + d[i]*Cos[2*Pi*i*t/P], {i, 1, k}] + 
   Sum[bb[i]*Sin[2*Pi*i*t/P0] + dd[i]*Cos[2*Pi*i*t/P0], {i, 1, k}];
paramsK = Join[{a0}, Table[b[i], {i, 1, k}], Table[d[i], {i, 1, k}], 
   Table[bb[i], {i, 1, k}], Table[dd[i], {i, 1, k}], {P}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {modelK, {85 < P < 90}}, paramsK, t];
spb = nlm["SinglePredictionBands"];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[{nlm[t], spb}, {t, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, LightGray, LightGray}]]
```

[image: Data and model fit]

The adequacy of either approach depends on how good you need the predictions to be (which is not an intrinsic property of the data).

Comment: very instructive.